# MS DI why Register Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Reading at this doc from MS DI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Keen to understand why we need these options:

```
Add{LIFETIME}<{IMPLEMENTATION}>()
Example:
services.AddScoped<MyDep>();

Add{LIFETIME}(new {IMPLEMENTATION})
Examples:
services.AddScoped(new MyDep());
services.AddScoped(new MyDep("A string!"));
```

What does it provide by doing above given that those new classes have no Interface implementation? DI container is mostly abstracted via Interface so that solution is loosely coupled.

Do we even need to register this.

Also is there any difference on below? I would think first one will suffice:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(ICertificateService), typeof(CertificateService));

serviceCollection.AddScoped(ICertificateService, CertificateService);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you cite, the chart shows that those two use cases are the only ones that provide all three characteristics (Automatic object disposal, Multiple implementations, and Pass args). There are several reasons to do this.

If the implementations implement `IDisposable`, the container will handle disposal automatically (no need for `using` blocks) - the first characteristic.

If you need multiple implementations (either two different classes implementing the same interface or one instance of a class that takes a constructor argument and another instance that doesn't), you can add them this way - the second characteristic.

The constructor argument can also come from the container if desired, since `IServiceProvider` is passed in - the third characteristic.

There are two other overloads listed that can take arguments; one has a type parameter but does not have the `IServiceProvider` passed in - it doesn't have automatic disposal; the other doesn't have either - it doesn't have automatic disposal or multiple implementations.

This way, you would inject an `IEnumerable<MyDep> myDeps`, then check it with something like:

```cs
var myDep = myDeps.Single(x => x.ReadOnlyProperty == "A string!");
```

Practically, this would be useful if one of the instances had another scoped service (like a `DbContext` or `UserManager`) which could simultaneously be handled by the container.

Part of your question was:

> What does it provide by doing above given that those new classes have no Interface implementation?

Although it doesn't make much sense initially (i.e. the classes could probably just be instantiated when needed), the pattern does contribute to "constructor honesty":

> If you define classes that can be constructed and called, but which will only function properly if certain global or infrastructure components are in place, these classes are being *dishonest* with their clients.

Ref: [Explicit dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#explicit-dependencies)

On the other hand, if the methods on `MyDep` were not virtual, they would be difficult to override in a mock for unit testing (which is why this pattern is not as common an injecting interfaces, where everything can be overridden in a mock).

It's worth noting as well that another reason this approach isn't as popular is you're tied to a specific implementation throughout your application - you're just moving the `new` keyword up into the container orchestration. ([New is Glue](https://ardalis.com/new-is-glue))

For your last question:

> Also is there any difference on below?

I think maybe you meant between these two?

```cs
serviceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(ICertificateService), typeof(CertificateService));
serviceCollection.AddScoped<ICertificateService, CertificateService>();
```

I believe the second is just a way to specify the service and its implementation as type parameters instead of having to use runtime reflection. But it wouldn't be enough, since it wouldn't handle situations where the type isn't known until runtime.